# 'svn list' can give different results

Tags: svn

I think I might have found a bug in 'svn list' but maybe it is expected. I want to know what you think.

I'm using svn client 1.7.10, windows.

Imagine this repo structure:
repoRoot
repoRoot/dir1
repoRoot/dir2
where repoRoot contains an svn:external to pull an external repo into repoRoot/dirExt.

"svn list -R url_to_repoRoot"
"svn list -R -rHEAD url_to_repoRoot"
Either of these commands list all files & dirs under repoRoot but does NOT report repotRoot/dirExt.

"svn list -R -r1511 url_to_repoRoot"
This command lists all files & dirs under repoRoot AND DOES report repotRoot/dirExt.

I would expect the -r1511 version to act like the previous 2 commands. Why is this happening? Is this expected behavior or have I found an svn bug that I should report?

Comment: Are you _certain_ `./dirExt` wasn't an actual dir in revision 1511, in other words: that it only became an external later? `svn list` should _never_ report an `svn:external` as a dir AFAIK.

Comment: Sometimes the most obvious answer is the right answer. You are correct, it did exist at that revision. Thanks!